# Getting the Co-ordinatades of middle point of Map - iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am making iPhone application in which i am using UIMapKit. I have a static pointer (Arrow) in the middle of screen of iPhone and behind that Pointer i am using iOS maps in which user interaction is enable , means user can move the map can zoom in or zoom out the map.

My task is to get the longitude and latitude of that location which comes under my Screen Pointer(Arrow)

Can anyone help me how can i do achieve this. I have very good command on UIMap i just need a idea

Comment: Did you mean you want the annotation on the map to be in the middle?

Comment: Did you try asking the map for its centerCoordinate?

Comment: what i want is ,whenever i move my map i get the co-ordinates of it's central position. e.g rite now the NewYork is at the centre of my map. i move my map and it get stop and now Tokyo is at the central position of map i want to get the co-ordinates of tokyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessary functionality is built in to `MapView`.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pinCoordinate = [self.pickupLocationView convertPoint:CGPointMake(self.pickupLocationView.frame.size.width / 2, self.pickupLocationView.frame.size.height) toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
```

This is `UIKit` as the poster requested. I believe Akash's solution would work if the question was about Google's map.

Comment: On - you can, as suggested, use 'centerCoordinate' as well, if you do not want to offset your arrow. We found that it looked better slightly offset, so here it is broken out.

Comment: Thank you tooluser i have implemented the technic which you have mentioned in your answer and that is working perfectly for me. thanks a lot.

Comment: Geek, you're welcome to go through posts and add back ticks if it's worth your time, but please don't correct my grammar incorrectly. Ouch!

Answer (score 3):

You can get middle point of screen using :

```
CGPoint screenCenterPoint = self.view.center;
```

and then convert it to coordinates using :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCenterPoint = [self.view convertPoint:screenCenterPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
```

If you use Google maps then you can use this ,too :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCenterPoint = [self.mapView.projection coordinateForPoint: screenCenterPoint];
```

To learn more look at [GMSProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection) and [GMSMapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view).

Comment: Thanks Akash for your response.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib Sorry, I did not look that you are not using google maps. Edited my answer so that others can get benefit.